# Finite measures that agree on null sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a measurable space $(S, \Sigma)$ and let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two finite measures
on $(S, \Sigma)$. Assume that for every $A \in \Sigma$, if $\mu(A) = 0$, then $\nu(A) = 0$. Show that, for every
$\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\eta>0$ such that, for all $A \in \Sigma$, if $\mu(A) < \eta$, then $\nu(A) < \varepsilon$.

My attempt:

The proof is by contradiction. Assume that for every $\eta >0$, there exists $\varepsilon >0$ and $B \in \Sigma$ such that $$\mu(B) < \eta \implies \nu(B) \geq \varepsilon.$$

Fix $\eta >0$ arbitrary. There exists a set $B$ in $\Sigma$ such that $\mu(B) < \eta$. Extract from $B$ a descending family of subsets $B_n$ such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(B_n) < \infty$.
Then we know that $\mu(\limsup_{n \to \infty} B_n)=0$ by Borel-Cantelli (Version 1). Since $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on null sets, it follows that $\nu(\limsup_{n \to \infty} B_n) =0$.

From continuity, we obtain $$\nu \left(\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=m}^\infty B_n \right)= \lim_{m \to \infty} \nu \left(\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty B_n \right) =0.$$

Therefore, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for $n \geq N$, we have $\nu(B_n) < \varepsilon$, a contradiction.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: The negative of the thesis is that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $\eta>0$ there is some $A_{\varepsilon,\eta}$ such that $\mu(A_{\varepsilon,\eta})<\eta$ and $\nu(A_{\varepsilon,\eta})\ge\varepsilon$.